# Duda sobre diseño de base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, uml

Estoy diseñando un sistema para un consultorio clínico y para ello se me ha propuesto el siguiente enunciado:

En esta clínica se encuentra un doctor y una secretaria.

El sistema tendrá dos módulos importantes, el módulo de la secretaria y el modulo del doctor.

La secretaria se encarga de registrar las citas para las consultas, cada cliente que solicita una cita, si no tiene expediente, se creará uno; de igual manera si no está registrado, se registrará. La secretaria vera en pantalla una tabla con todas las citas a ejecutar cada día(según los registros que haya hecho en ese día).   También podrá escoger ver un historial de citas pasadas.

El doctor verá una tabla con las citas a ejecutar (el doctor sabe a quién va atender antes que la persona entre al consultorio) y en esa tabla, por cada paciente podrá ver el expediente médico y en la consulta podrá modificarlo para agregar el diagnóstico de la presente consulta, además podrá generar constancias de consulta, recetas médicas y otros documentos que estime importantes en formato PDF listos para imprimir. 
Cuando el doctor termine la consulta, dará por finalizada esa cita, y lo que se agregó al expediente, queda guardado para posteriores consultas del paciente.

Por el momento he diseñado la siguiente base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con respecto al diseño que he realizado me surgen dos preguntas.

1-¿Puedo hacer que la llave primaria de la tabla "paciente" sea foránea de dos tablas como lo es en la tabla "expediente" y la tabla "citas"?

2-¿En este caso, mi tabla "usuario" podría no relacionarse con ninguna otra tabla o indudablemente se tiene que relacionar con alguna otra tabla?

Comment: por estandar las llaves primarias son llamados id, para diseña una agenda medica le recomiendo utiliza la siguiente libreria https://fullcalendar.io/ en la cual permiter tener una agenda con calendario y fechas, le hace falta la tabla de horario por médicos ya que cada medico tiene un horario especifico

Answer (score 1):

1. Si, se puede hacer sin problemas.
2. Puede no existir la necesidad de relacionarla a ninguna tabla, la pregunta que creo debes hacerte es ¿en algún momento voy a necesitar saber quién dio de alta una cita (u otro registro)? ¿Saber quién lo modificó? Si la respuesta es no entonces no existe necesidad de relacionar la tabla de usuarios a ninguna otra.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Te invito a leer [answer]. Tu respuesta es deficiente. En el punto 1, ¿puedes explicar el porqué se puede hacer ***sin problemas***? Por otro lado, dado que se trabaja con información tan delicada como un expediente o historial médico, ¿crees que es prudente decir: ***Puede no existir la necesidad***? Si consideras que puedes mejorar tu respuesta, te invito a que uses el botón de [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/255569/edit) y lo hagas. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta es muy abierta debes ir afinando tu modelo y hacer preguntas mas especificas dependiendo de la tarea que realices.

Así que  primero separa o reagrupa los elementos por procesos,

```
Cita   
-Paciente   
-Recepcionista
-Doctor
-LibroDeCitas
```

Para cada proceso define un flujo,

El Paciente contacta a Recepcionista si es primera cita, la recepcionista verifica que el paciente no este registrado  y registra al Paciente, en el primer registro solo se preguntan datos básicos, Nombre, teléfono, Motivo de cita, edad,...Cuando el paciente tenga su primera cita puede complementar su información,Aseguradora,email, dirección,RFC,ect.

El recepcionista, verifica la disponibilidad en el libro de citas o agenda y le da opciones al paciente, el paciente aprueba un horario.

El recepcionista, agenda la cita.

-Posibles siguentes casos :
 -El paciente llega a la cita (flujo ideal)

- El paciente Cancela la cita.
- El paciente Reagenda la cita.
- El doctor Cancela, no estará disponible ese día.

Tablas involucradas

```
Consultorio
-----------
ConsultorioId
Nombre
DireccionId  
Telefono
Email
ImagenLogo
Slogan

PersonalConsultorio
--------------------
PersonalConsultorioId
Nombre
Apellidos
DireccionId
Email
Telefono
RolPersonalId
RolPersonal

RolPersonal  (Doctor, Recepcionista, Enfermera, Mantenimiento)
--------------
RolPersonalld
RolNombre
RolDescripcion

Pacientes
-----------
PacienteId
Nombre
AseguradoraId
DireccionId
Telefono1
Telefono2
Email
Rfc

AgendaCitas
--------------
CitaId
PacienteId
DoctorId(==PersonalConsultorioId) 
Fecha
HoraInicio
HoraFin
EsDisponible
RazonCancelacion
EsCancelada
```

El análisis y diseño es un proceso que se trabaja varias veces, incluso aun cuando ya estés apunto de terminar la aplicación.

Lo te ayudara mucho es ir trabajando en las interfaces de Usuario, ejemplo citas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces para cada actividad en la que tengas problemas es mejor que agregues un problema en especifico, ya sea diseño, código , tablas.

Saludos